# how to display errors on the same page (php form)

Tags: php, forms

Trying to display errors on the same page. How do I do that? As this stands right now, every time there are errors, it generates a blank page with all the errors listed.

I don't want that.

Here's a basic form that I ripped off from a tutorial somewhere `test.php`:

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

        <form name="form1" method="post" action="test2.php">
        Name: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" size="50" /><br/><br/>
        Email Address: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" size="50"/> <br/><br/>
        Home Page: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="homepage" value="<?php echo $_POST['homepage']; ?>" size="50" /> <br/><br/>
        Message: <br/>
        <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="50"><?php echo $_POST['message']; ?></textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the php code for it that was also ripped off from the tutorial, ie, `test2.php`:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

        if ($_POST['name'] != "") {
            $_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            if ($_POST['name'] == "") {
                $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {
            $errors .= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
        }

        if ($_POST['email'] != "") {
            $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $errors .= "$email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/><br/>";
            }
        } else {
            $errors .= 'Please enter your email address.<br/>';
        }

        if ($_POST['homepage'] != "") {
            $homepage = filter_var($_POST['homepage'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            if (!filter_var($homepage, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
                $errors .= "$homepage is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid URL.<br/><br/>";
            }
        } else {
            $errors .= 'Please enter your home page.<br/>';
        }

        if ($_POST['message'] != "") {
            $_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            if ($_POST['message'] == "") {
                $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
            }
        } else {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
        }

        if (!$errors) {
            $mail_to = 'me@somewhere.com';
            $subject = 'New Mail from Form Submission';
            $message  = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n";
            $message .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
            $message .= 'Homepage: ' . $_POST['homepage'] . "\n";
            $message .= "Message:\n" . $_POST['message'] . "\n\n";
            mail($to, $subject, $message);

            echo "Thank you for your email!<br/><br/>";
        } else {
            echo '<div style="color: red">' . $errors . '<br/></div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Note, I added the `session_start` to both pages because I'd like the errors done via that instead of `GET`.

How do I have the errors show up on `test.php` form?

Answer (score -1):

I would use sessions to represent errors on the same page.

start the session on test2.php

```
session_start();
```

then create session errors in the if statements you need

```
$_SESSION['error'] = 'error message here';
header('location:test1.php');
        exit;
```

then on test1.php, something like this

```
    <?php
        session_start();
    
        if (!empty($_SESSION['error'])){
    ?>
    <div class="alert"> //you could then style this div to present error message better
    <?php
        echo $_SESSION['error'];
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
        }
    ?>
   </div>
```

or have it without the divs in one php statement to just simply echo the error.

Comment: thank you for responding! Can I ask a question if you don't mind? I'm a tad confused how you're supposed to put the session errors in the if statements ...

Comment: I just added an edit to see if that's what you meant ... is it?

Comment: Yeah, works for me in some of the work I've done... I'm still noobish to it though. did it work?